# Convergence of the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

So I tried the absolute convergence:
$ \frac{\lvert \sin(3n)\rvert}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \ge \frac{\sin^2(3n)}{n} \sim \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{\cos 6n}{2n} $.$ \frac{1}{2n} $ doesn't converge, while $ \frac{\cos 6n}{2n} $ converge, so the whole series doesn't converge absolutely. But I don't know how to prove, if it converge or not at all. I stacked here:
$ \frac{(-1)^n\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\sin(3n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{\cos n(\frac{\pi}{2}-3) - \cos n(\frac{\pi}{2}+3)}{2\sqrt{n^2+1}} $. Help with the next step or explain a different solution please.

Comment: Use [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Abel's Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abel%27s_Lemma):

*If $\{b_n\}$ is non-negative, decreasing and tends to zero, and the partial sums of $\{a_n\}$ are bounded, then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.*

Here:

$$
a_n=(-1)^n\sin(3n), \quad b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.
$$

Comment: okey, thanks, i was not sure where to put $ (-1)^n $ in this rule.